# How do I stop a webservice endpoint?

Tags: java, web-services

I understand that I need to call the stop() method using the endpoint. 
But I am not sure how to call it.

Here's my code

```
public class Publish {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String address = "http://localhost:8483/cal";
        Object implementor =  new CalWebserviceImpl();

        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
        System.out.println(endpoint.isPublished());

        endpoint.stop();


    } // main
}
```

And this is the error I get:

**Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:117)**

I assume that I am getting the error message because I am trying to (re-)publish the endpoint before stopping it.

I tried to create a new endpoint reference and use it to stop it.

```
        Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(implementor);
        ep.stop();
```

But I am getting the same error message.

I am just unclear how to call the stop() the service. Please advise. Thank you!

**Edit:**

Here's another unsuccessful attempt:

```
package com.website.test;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Unpublish {

    Endpoint ep = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Unpublish up = new Unpublish();
        up.run();

    } // main


     public void run(){      
            String address = "http://localhost:8483/cal";
            Object implementor =  new CalWebserviceImpl();  
            // my service is already running, I believe it's publish here that's causing the issue       
            ep = Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);

            startWebService();          
   }

    private void startWebService() {

        if(ep.isPublished()){           
            System.out.println("Endpoint webservice is running!");
        }
        else{
            ep.stop();
            System.out.println("Endpoint webservice stopped!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487762/publish-and-stop-endpoint-web-service-in-java

Comment: I read the before but it doesn't resolve my issue. The initial step is still to publish the service. I'm posting my edited version of the code above in my question.

Comment: Do you have some rogue instance already running ?

Comment: Restarting my computer terminated the local webservice (localhost:8483/cal). I was able to call the run() method successfully afterwards (1 time only). The second start I called the run() method, I get the "service already running error". 

So the issue I am trying to resolve is how to stop the service on demand without using the publish() method that's causing the "service already running error". But it seems like I need to use the publish() method to create the Endpoint instance which I eventually use to stop the service. Simply put, how do I call just stop() instead of publish() stop();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to gracefully close an Endpoint when an exception occurs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610303/how-to-gracefully-close-an-endpoint-when-an-exception-occurs)